# Will events be acknowledged if the thread is dead (but process is alive)

Tags: java, multithreading

Class A starts a new thread as shown below:

```
class A {
Thread t = new Thread(new B());
t.start();
}
```

Class B has an event handler on a button called "myButton" which is actually a GPIO pin monitoring for input.

```
Class B implements Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
   myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
            // display pin state on console
            System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
        }

    });
}
System.out.println("Thread gets out here.....");
}
```

When `t.start()` is called in ClassA the thread (call it threadA) in ClassA waits for the new spawn thread (call it threadB) to return (since the threadB is not daemon thread). Inside the `run()` method in ClassB the event is added to myButton and the threadB gets out ClassB and eventually the threadA in ClassA also ends (since thread B has returned).

**Question:** After all of the above (i.e. both threads A and B ending) say there was an event on myButton i.e. the GPIO pin received an input, would the listener(myButton) acknowledge the event OR it wouldn't since the threads are not active? I would assume as long as the process which started the threads is active the event would be acknowledged i.e say ClassA is part of a servlet call. Is that correct?

Comment: Better to form use cases you asked by your own & try to figure out what will happen. That would be best understandable to you. :)

Comment: Class B does not _have_ an event handler:  The `run()` method of Class B _creates_ a new `GpioPinListenerDigital` instance, and registers that new object as a listener for `myButton`.  Neither the `myButton` object nor the new `GpioPinListenerDigital` object has any knowledge of (or any connection to) the thread that your `class A` created.

Comment: What is the purpose of the thread that your `class A` creates?  The runnable object that you give to that thread does nothing but create a handler object, register the handler object, and then exit.  What problem do you hope to solve by doing that in its own thread?

Comment: The `class A {...}` from your example is not compilable Java code.  Those two statements that create and start a new thread belong in an executable block somewhere (e.g., in a method body).  Just curious, where do they really appear in your program, and when are they executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent()` should continue to be invoked after the initializing threads terminate.

In fact, you shouldn't need to start a new thread to add a listener. Just add the listener directly to your button. An additional thread would be useful to do something that might take a long time. But simply registering an event listener can be expected to be fast.

Inside your `handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent()` method, try printing the name of the thread (`Thread.currentThread().getName()`) too. You will probably see that it's a runtime thread that you didn't start yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the most simple implementation of the Observable / Observer pattern, it doesn't matter which thread the Observer registers itself with the Observable, as the Observer will be get the call back notification on the thread that caused the event to trigger in Observable.